# Relationship between vectors perpendicular to a given vector

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

Let vectors 
$a=a_1i+a_2j+a_3k$
$b=b_1i+b_2j+b_3k$
$c=c_1i+c_2j+c_3k$
be such that
$a\cdot b=0$  and  $a\cdot c=0 $
Then how are vectors b and c related mathematicaly

Comment: What dimension is the vector space? Can we assume $a,\,b,\,c$ are all nonzero vectors?

Comment: you mean $a = a_1 i + a_2 j + a_3 k$ and so on ?

Comment: Yes... And both are non zero